# Memory management in NotificationServiceExtension inside framework

Tags: swift, memory, frameworks, ios-extensions

It's quite something new for me but I I'm facing issue with memory management in NotificationServiceExtension. To give an idea of the problem I will shortly describe situation:

Framework mainly is used for handling push notifications. It also uses rich notifications. Developer in order to use our framework has to import it in his NotificationServiceExtension and use our class as superclass. Unfortunately this is when memory issue appears . NotificationServiceExtension can only handle 12 mb of RAM so even 1mb of memory is important for us. I noticed that when user uses our framework (imports it) it will also load all imports that framework has in classes. 
So for eg.

I have one class in framework that is responsible for showing SafariViewController, in order to do that I have to import `SafariServices`.  This import consumes 2.5mb of RAM when NotificationServiceExtension launches. I would like to highlight that extension never uses this class, but it exists in framework. Moreover even if framework never uses this class but it only exists as file it is also allocated in Extension.

Anyone faced issue like this? I'm wondering how I can prevent Extension from allocating all framework imports?